# SQL: How can I get the items value in one row using sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get the items value in one row using sql query like `20,10,15,40,15`?

Table Name : `ites`

```
id  |   items
===============
1   |   20
2   |   10
3   |   15
4   |   40
5   |   15
```

As example we can get sum like this

```
Query
SELECT SUM(items) FROM `ites`

Result
SUM(items)
100
```

In same manner I want to get the value like `20,10,15,40,15` using a query?

Comment: There's no reason why you'd want to do this- but obviously you can look at what other aggregating functions are available

Comment: @Strawberry can you please tell me that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/):

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(items) FROM ites
```

Comment: I don't  want same value with comma separate, I want all values with comma seprate

Comment: @BachchaSingh That's exactly what my answer will give you. See the update.

Comment: Thanks I am looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the IDs of item

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(items)as myvalues FROM ites

With multiple occurrence of items
SELECT  ID
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(items AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM iten 
         WHERE ID = t.ID
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') myvalues
FROM iten t
GROUP BY ID
```